# Is operator void*() conversion still part of C++ library?

Tags: c++, g++, cout, delete-operator, conversion-operator

Consider this program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    delete std::cout;
}
```

AFAIK the conversion function **operator void* () const** has been removed from C++11. So, this program should fail in compilation on a C++11 compiler. Ya, its true that both g++ 4.8.1 & 4.9.2 gives diagnosis (in the form of warning that deleting void* is undefined & that's also the good thing). But shouldn't this program fail in compilation because removal of that conversion function due to which all stream object could be implicitly converted to void* in C++98 & C++03?. Is this bug? It seems bit surprising that they still not have implemented this change.

I've tried this program in g++ 4.9.2(that supports C++14) but it gives warning not compiler error. Ideone compiler gives me an error as expected. (See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/chhi9z))

Comment: *"Ideone compiler"* is actually GCC 5.1

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: The question isn't about that. The question is why program still compiles in g++ 4.8.1 & 4.9.2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the compiler, its a library issue. libstdc++ has lots of incompatibilities with C++11, of which this is just one. They are making breaking changes in 5 and up though iirc.

In short, it's neither a bug nor a compiler issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the standard library (if you view it as an implementation of the C++11/14 standard library rather than C++98/03).

It's sort of a compiler issue as well though. Specifically, removing the conversion to `void *` depends on adding a conversion directly to `bool`--but that, in turn, depends on adding "contextual conversion" to the compiler.

gcc 4.8 did implement a form of contextual conversion, but not the form that was accepted into the standard. Although the specific changes to contextual conversion wouldn't *directly* impact this use of contextual conversion, it does point to the fact that the definition of contextual conversion was still being tweaked as these compilers were being written.

The sequence in which things (at least normally) happen is that first the specification is solidified. Then the compiler implements it. Then the standard library puts it to use.

In this case the specification was still changing fairly shortly before the compiler was released. Therefore, the standard library didn't (and practically speaking, couldn't) use it.

By the time of 4.9, the specification was solid, and the compiler implemented the final version of contextual conversion, but it hadn't been around long enough to be put to use in the standard library yet.